# Rails - Creating postgres database on server throws error "could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've been trying to get my app running for a couple of days now, and all previous problems were answered by searching, but I can't find a solution for this problem.

So I managed to deploy my app to a webhost following this guide: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

now I've come to the step were I need to perform the following action:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
```

I do this SSHing to deploy@[server IP] and going into the current folder, but it throws the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in `block in create_current'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:183:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `create_current'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/musicBlog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"dbblog", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"[removed]", "host"=>"localhost"}
```

this is the database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dbblog
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: [password removed!]
  host: localhost
```

I used the same host as the writer of the guide author, and followed the same steps, so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

I hope somebody can help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: did you add `gem 'pg'` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes, and I think it would've thrown an error at me when I ran `cap production deploy` if I hadn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check is whether your local Postgres instance is running at all:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

And then if so, on what port it's running. `5432` is the default, so if you didn't do anything special in terms of config, that's where it should be running.

Also: Is the server where you're doing the `rake` the same one on which `Postgres` is running?

Comment: I used the command on both the server and local, both gives this kind of output:
`deploy    1225  1067  0 11:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres`
(only local there are seven or eight of these lines) 
I've no idea how to check on which port it's running, but I didn't configure anything, so this should be good (isn't localhost automatically port `5432`?)

Comment: Thats the entirety of the output? There should be a bunch of postgres-related processes, including the `postmaster daemon` process, which will likely end in `bin\postgres` and should include the path to the data directory, where you can look to see what the port is configured as (just to double check). There should also be other processes, such as `wal writer`. The last one is just the grep itself, so that will always appear.

Comment: Yes, that's it. if I run it local however it outputs a lot more, also the `wal writer` progress, but not the postmaster daemon (but however, this is local, the problem is on the server.) There also isn't a postgres folder in my server's `bin`.

Comment: If on the server that's the only output then it would appear that Postgres is not running there, which is why you would get that error message. You installed `Postgres` on the **server** as is mentioned in the Rails guide you linked? If so, you should be able to start it up. Postgres generally would not be located in `bin`. Is there a file in `/etc/init.d` that starts with `postgresql`?

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! thanks to your help and some googling I managed to start the database, now whenever I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create` I get: `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` I tried changing the password by using `sudo -u postgres psql` and then `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newPassword';` (I set the password the same as in database.yml, which it was already I'm pretty sure) but I still get the password authentication error.

Comment: Well, I figured it out by editing the `pg_hba.conf` file and created a db! I don't know what I have to do next.. I created the database, used `touch myapp/current/tmp/restart.txt` (replacing 'myapp' with the name of my app of course) but when I visit my site it gives me an error page, when I try to see the log file by CDing to `nginx` I get the error: `-bash: cd: nginx: Permission denied`.

Comment: You're welcome. On the subsequent issue, I'm not an `nginx` expert, but one thing you might try for that is making sure you're the same user as `nginx` is running under to `cd` into the log dir. Most likely its permissions are set such that a regular user couldn't access that directory. From the tutorial you linked, it's implied that it might be **root**.

Comment: You were right, I gave my deploy user permission to check out the log file :) It's up and running now so no worries! Thanks again for the help.